# WPF, how to determine when a MediaElement has finished playing the movie?

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I am showing a movie on my application, and i want the application to only play it once. And when its done playing i want to enable some buttons (play, rewind, watch again etc...) but is there any way i can get an event when the movie has finished - or anything that would accomplish this scenario?

Cheers,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [MediaElement.MediaEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended.aspx) event should help you